# How to override an inner class with a concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a class that contain another class. I want to have the possibility to change the second class with a concern.

Here is the code :

```
class BaseClass
  class InnerClass
    def sample;    puts 'sample'; end 
    def self.yolo; puts 'yolo';   end
  end
end

BaseClass::InnerClass.yolo       # yolo
BaseClass::InnerClass.new.sample # sample

module UglyButNeededPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class NewInnerClass
      def sample;    puts 'new sample'; end 
      def self.yolo; puts 'new yolo';   end
    end
    class InnerClass
      def sample;    super(); puts 'rewrite'; end 
      def self.yolo; super(); puts 'rewrite';   end
    end
  end
end

BaseClass.__send__(:include, UglyButNeededPatch)
```

This work fine

```
BaseClass::NewInnerClass.yolo       # new yolo
BaseClass::NewInnerClass.new.sample # new sample
```

This Does not work

```
BaseClass::InnerClass.yolo       # still display yolo
BaseClass::InnerClass.new.sample # still display sample
```

Is there a way to make `BaseClass::InnerClass.yolo` display `yolorewrite` and `BaseClass::InnerClass.new.sample` display `samplerewrite`

Comment: "*This work fine*" and "*This Does not work*" blocks have the same code!

Comment: yeah, I notice after post. sorry for that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely replace the constant like this, for example:

```
module UglyButNeededPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |base|
    base::InnerClass = Class.new do
      def sample;    puts 'rewrite'; end 
      def self.yolo; puts 'rewrite';   end
    end
  end
end
```

And if you want to surgically patch the inner class, the easiest way I found is to use another concern:

```
module UglyButNeededPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |base|
    base::InnerClass.include(InnerClassPatch)
  end

  module InnerClassPatch
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def sample; puts 'rewrite'; end

    module ClassMethods
      def yolo; puts 'rewrite'; end
    end
  end
end
```